# Delete files in directory without erroring if it's already empty

Tags: files, rm

As part of a deployment script, I want to dump some cached stuff from my temp directory. I use a command like:

```
rm /tmp/our_cache/*
```

However, if `/tmp/our_cache` is empty (fairly common when pushing many changes in quick succession to our testing server), this prints the following error message:

```
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/our_cache/*': No such file or directory
```

It's not a big deal, but it's a little ugly and I want to cut down the noise-to-signal ratio in the output from this script.

What's a concise way in unix to delete the contents of a directory without getting messages complaining that the directory is already empty?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Since you presumably want to remove all files without prompting, why not just use the `-f` switch to `rm` to ignore nonexistent files?

```
rm -f /tmp/our_cache/*
```

From man page:

```
-f, --force
          ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
```

Also, if there may be any subdirectories in `/tmp/our_cache/` and you want those and their contents deleted as well, don't forget the `-r` switch.

Comment: most obvious solution and I did not think about it! I feel like the first guy on this comic https://xkcd.com/399/ ;-)

Answer (score 7):

```
find /tmp/our_cache/ -mindepth 1 -delete
```

**Edit 1**

removed "-type f

**Edit 2**

Added non-standard option `-mindepth 1` in order to prevent the search root directory to be removed (after taking the `-type f` limitation away).

Comment: Just a note, I'd leave out `-type f` since there may be temporary directories as well (although the example in the question doesn't account for them, so they're probably not there...)

Comment: using `-type f` will only delete regular files, so symbolic links for example would not be deleted.

Comment: @rush Sorry, I didn't check that but just had a look at the man pages which says "Delete files", not mentioning directories anyhow. I delete my comment.

Comment: That removes `/tmp/our_cache` so you might as well do `rm -r /tmp/our_cache`. While you're at using non-standard options, you could use `-mindepth 1`. Note that contrary to `rm /tmp/our_cache/*`, it also removes subdirectories and their content and hidden files.

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect the standard error to `/dev/null` so that it wont print this

```
$  rm /tmp/our_cache/* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also suppress errors shown if, say, a file can't be deleted because it is in use? The only error I want to suppress is the one shown if the target directory is empty; this seems like it would have unwanted side effects.

Comment: Even if you try to delete some file which some process has opened, you wont get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (though slightly overkill...):

```
[ ! -z "$(ls -A /tmp/our_cache/)" ] && rm -rf /tmp/our_cache/*
```

this uses `test` or `[` to test if the string returned from running an `ls` on your directory is not empty.  Then if, and only if, that string is NOT empty does it remove everything under your directory.

**NOTE:** leaving the glob out of the `ls` will suppress the error of no files.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is usin BASH you can try:

```
if test "$(ls /tmp/our_cache/)" !=  ""; then rm /tmp/our_cache/*; fi
```

Doing so will still produce an error if there is a "real" problem or if a file is protected (you would then need the `-f` modifier of `rm` to delete this type of files) but will avoid the error when no files is there.

If you use another shell than BASH for your scripting, such as zsh, ksh, you can try this other syntax which might be more portable:

```
if [[ "$(ls /tmp/our_cache/)" !=  "" ]]; then rm /tmp/our_cache/*; fi
```